# $_SESSION['user_id'] is enough to check login in PHP?

Tags: php, authentication

When a user logged in website, I only save `user_id` in SESSION to check it later whether user logged in or not.

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){
  ....
```

Is this enough for security?

Comment: Careful: There might be a user with `id == 0`.

Comment: Yes, so use isset()!
See also my answer.

Comment: Technically, and considering just the basic case, *yes*. Apart from that, you should re-use an existing authentication framework whenever possible, because, really, it's complex. For example, take a look at https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Auth which is both framework-agnostic and database-agnostic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This would depend entirely on how that variable makes it to the session and how well you're managing session.

One case to always consider when dealing with web-site security and user credentials is the possibility of a user logging on to your site in a public environment and then walking away. How long will he stay logged in? How accessible is the sensitive information when already logged in?

If you have a relatively short session timeout and are making sure that you are managing what makes it into $_SESSION['user_id'] then this is a reasonable approach. It may be better to actually check the VALUE of what is in $_SESSION['user_id'] but that won't be a huge improvement over what you currently have.

The main thing that I would recommend taking into account would be to require login credentials once more if a user ever wants to alter their account's details / access overly sensitive data (you wouldn't want a stranger changing your users' login names would you?). While this may be a bit of a hassle for regular users, it definitely adds a good measure of security to your application.

Answer (score 7):

The value could only be changed if someone has access to the session files.

So usually **yes**.

But I would rather use [`isset()`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.isset.php):

```
function loggedIn()
{
  if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && is_numeric($_SESSION['user_id']))
    return true;
  return false;
}
```

Because if the user id is 0, [`empty()`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.empty.php) will also return true!

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a shared hosting environment, somebody else on the same server could potentially create a valid session and gain access.

Or, someone could be sniffing network traffic as one of your users visits the site and could catch the cookie and gain access to their account since you just using simple session based authentication.

A common way to fix this problem is to create a database table, perhaps called "sessions", and record the session id, IP address, and any other user-specific data you want to gather when the user first logs in. You can then repeatedly check against this session table to help ensure that it is indeed the original user logged in and not somebody else.

Comment: Yes, you right. I've already had a session table in DB. It is more secure. Thanks though

Comment: @dino - Great, you're already ahead of the game then. As long as you make sure to use isset() as others have mentioned and check your logged in users against the sessions table, you should be good security wise for user sessions. There are other strategies you could employ for added security and even go as far as cryptographic protocols to secure the actual data being transmitted, but for most generic sites you should be perfectly fine with what you have. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It depends...

if you never do something like $_SESSION['user_id'] = $_GET['user_id'] you can usually say: it is save.

BUT there are things like session hijacking, cross site scripting, cross site request forgeries, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if(!isset($_SESSION($user_id){
```

Because if the $user_id==0 then isempty() will not work and be sure that the session which is not required on another page must be unset after the page end for the better security. The method to unset a particular session variable is

```
unset($_session_variable_name);
```

and the session should be destroyed whenever it is required ie when a user logout.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Not really, apart from the comments above you should further check properties like IP-address or USER_AGENT to avoid session-hijacking.

Comment: A session based on a fixed IP is a bad thing. IP's are not always static between requests..

Comment: Those have been two examples, there may be other ways to re-check a valid session. However, an IP-based session may not be good, but it's really bad to rely only on a session-ID